# Unable to set correct resolution for each monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have 2 monitors that are connected to Dell Dock WD19:

1. Ultrawide Xiaomi Mi Curved Gaming Monitor (DP to DP)
2. Dell IPS P2722H 27" (HDMI port on monitor to DP)

When both are connected, the resolution of ultrawide monitor drops to 1920x1080 (like Dell monitor) and I am unable to increase it.
When I disconnect Dell monitor, it works fine 3440x1440. How can I make the ultrawide monitor to work with correct resolution when Dell is connected?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a limitation of the WD19 dock. One solution, though messier, may be to connect one monitor through the dock and the other directly to your computer.

You can also try lowering the refresh rate on the Dell.

I've had similar issues when using two identical 1440p monitors even using that specific dock, and it took a bit of time to even figure out how to specify which monitor would be limited.